# Get output of subprocess after Keyboard Interrupt

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to store into a variable the last output of a subprocess after the user performs a Keyboard Interrupt. My problem is mainly with a subprocess without end, i.e. tail in my exemple below. Here is my code:

```
class Testclass:
    def Testdef(self):
        try:
            global out
            print "Tail running"
            tail_cmd='tail -f log.Reconnaissance'
            proc = subprocess.Popen([tail_cmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
            (out, err) = proc.communicate()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("KeyboardInterrupt received, stopping…")
        finally:
            print "program output:", out

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Testclass()
    app.Testdef()
```

Below is its output, which I don't understand at this moment.

```
Tail running
program output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./2Test.py", line 19, in <module>
    app.Testdef()
  File "./2Test.py", line 15, in Testdef
    print "program output:", out
NameError: global name 'out' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

`out` not being defined indicates that the process `proc.communicate()` did not return any values, otherwise it would have populated your tuple `(out, err)`. Now to find out whether the `communicate()` method was supposed to return or whether, more likely, your keyboard interrupt simply killed it, thus preventing `out` from being defined.

---

I assume you imported the `subprocess` module, but make sure you do that first. I rewrote your program without using `global out` or the `try` statements.

```
import subprocess
class Testclass:
    def __init__(self,out):    # allows you to pass in the value of out
        self.out = out    # makes out a member of this class
    def Testdef(self):
        print("Tail running")
        tail_cmd='tail -f log.Reconnaissance'
        proc = subprocess.Popen([tail_cmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        # Perhaps this is where you want to implement the try:
        (self.out, err) = proc.communicate()
        # and here the except:
        # and here the finally:

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Testclass(1)    # pass 1 (or anything for testing) to the out variable
    app.Testdef()
    print('%r' % app.out) # print the contents of the out variable
                          # i get an empty string, ''
```

---

So as-is this program runs once. There is nothing in `out`. I believe to create a meaningful example of the user doing a keyboard interrupt, we need the program to be doing something that can be interrupted. Maybe I can provide an example in the future...

Comment: Ah ok...And what way can i use for preventing that or get around this problem ?

Comment: EDIT: I get empty string too...I get stuck on my problem. Thanks anyway !